# Export const in react

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys how can I export my `const history` to use the same history in another component.
I try to use this history for use `history.push` in antoher views and components .

```
export function login(data) {

const history = createBrowserHistory({
forceRefresh: true
})

const endpoint = '/api/auth/jwt/'
const csrfToken = cookie.load('csrftoken')
let thisComp = this
if (csrfToken !== undefined) {
  let lookupOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'

      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      credentials: 'include'
  }

  fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions)
  .then(function(response){
      return response.json()
  }).then(function(responseData){
      console.log(responseData)
      localStorage.token = responseData.token
      localStorage.expires = responseData.expires // Store the token
      console.log("Token Stored", localStorage.token)
      console.log("Token Expires", responseData.expires)
      refreshToken(localStorage.token)
      history.push('/meals/')


    }).catch(function(error){

      console.log("error", error)
  })
}

}
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

You should move your const definition outside the login and export it, like below

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory({
forceRefresh: true
})

export function login(data) { ... }
```

Then you can import it from outside in this way

```
import { history } from 'pathToTheFile';
```